# I want frame of a subview w.r.t to window and superview of the same subview is transformed ( scaled, rotated)

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, cgaffinetransform, coordinate-transformation

In the image we need to find the frame for inner square wrt to windows. Normat cgRect : to method is giving wrong answer.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Have you searched for a solution? What have you found that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @DonMag I will be good if you can provide an answer to the question. I will definitely go through the link you have provided but please I need an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A much better method than my previous answer, and will handle subviews regardless of ratio / centering.

You can get the "innerView" frame like this:

```
innerView.frame = outerView.convert(innerView.frame, to: view)
```